# How do I apply taxes to orders?

Tags: 8, commerce

I have just installed fresh copy of commerce 2.x-dev and done initial steps as per "Getting Started with Commerce 2" doc. I have added some test products using default product type and variation (prices added exclusive of VAT). Furthermore, I have added zones and imported tax rates.

But ... In store settings I have disabled "Prices are entered with taxes included." option and now, I am wondering that how I'm able to apply taxes to orders in a way that tax amount is added to order's total and shown in order summary view at checkout?

Any hints / directions to go forward ...